# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Change CheckBox Display

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I have a `DataGridview` which lets the user do an assignment (`room` -> `activity`) with `Checkboxes`.

Each `column` represents a `room`. Each `row` represents an `activity`.

It is completly working. Now I want to make the `CheckBoxes` look better (thick green tick for `True`, thick red x for `False`) to make it more comfortable for the user to get an overview. The tick and the x can be everything they need to be; simple `ascii characters` or `images` - Whatever gets it working.

The following code is used for creating the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns.

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt_rooms.Rows
        Dim a As DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn = New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(False)
        a.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup
        a.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
        a.ToolTipText = row.Item("room")
        a.Name = row.Item("room")
        a.CellTemplate.Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.White
        dgv.Columns.Add(a)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so is to handle the `DataGridView.CellPainting` event. In this handle, you could, for example, change the background cell color depending on the cell value (checked or not).

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for example.